# How do I filter an array of arrays for certain characters with grep?

Tags: ruby

How do I filter an array of arrays for certain characters with grep?

```
examp = [["ram"], ["bam"], ["mam"], ["jammy"], ["grammy"], ["foobar"], ["clamjam"]]

foo = examp.grep(/[^am]/)
p foo
```

This is the expected output:

```
[["ram"], ["bam"], ["mam"], ["jammy"], ["grammy"], ["clamjam"]]
```

This is the actual output:

```
[]
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of arrays, each of which does not match a regex. A regex matches a string but not an array. That is what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you have would work if `examp` were an array of strings, but it's an array of single-element arrays.

Also, braces `[]`s inside a regex stand for character classes, whereas outside of a regex it delimits ruby arrays. The first does not match the latter.

Instead, do

```
foo = examp.select { |a| a[0][/am/] }
# => [["ram"], ["bam"], ["jammy"], ["grammy"], ["foobar"], ["clamjam"]]
```

---

Alternatively, if you want just the array of strings, you can do

```
foo = examp.flatten.grep(/am/)
# => ["ram", "bam", "mam", "jammy", "grammy", "clamjam"]
```

Comment: Why do your solutions contain 'foobar'?  That's precisely the only array without am; foobar is the one I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: @user3116998 In that case you want `/am/` for the regex. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be:

```
p examp.collect{|t| t if t.first =~ /am/ }.compact
```

result:

```
[["ram"], ["bam"], ["mam"], ["jammy"], ["grammy"], ["clamjam"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of different ways to skin this cat, but I'd start with:

```
examp = [["ram"], ["bam"], ["mam"], ["jammy"], ["grammy"], ["foobar"], ["clamjam"]]
examp.select{ |ary| ary.any?{ |a| a['am'] } }
# => [["ram"], ["bam"], ["mam"], ["jammy"], ["grammy"], ["clamjam"]]
```

That selects the sub-arrays whose elements contain the sub-string `'am'`. Here's an example with multiple elements in the sub-arrays to show what it'll do with a match or no match:

```
examp = [%w[ram], %w[foo bam], %w[mam foo], %w[foo], %w[foo bar]]
examp.select{ |ary| ary.any?{ |a| a['am'] } }
# => [["ram"], ["foo", "bam"], ["mam", "foo"]]
```

Notice that no regular expressions were needed to do this. A simple sub-string search using [String's `[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method handles the task nicely. Also, `grep` could be used, but not how you did it.

If you want to find the elements in the sub-arrays that contain the sub-string:

```
examp.map{ |ary| ary.select{ |a| a['am'] } }
# => [["ram"], ["bam"], ["mam"], [], []]
```

This could have been done using `grep`:

```
examp.map{ |ary| ary.grep(/am/) }
# => [["ram"], ["bam"], ["mam"], [], []]
```

If you want to get rid of the empty sub-arrays:

```
examp.map{ |ary| ary.select{ |a| a['am'] } }.reject(&:empty?)
# => [["ram"], ["bam"], ["mam"]]
```

`flatten` the result if you want to get rid of the sub-arrays:

```
examp.map{ |ary| ary.select{ |a| a['am'] } }.reject(&:empty?).flatten
# => ["ram", "bam", "mam"]
```